# How to integrate Fellowship

Tags: parachain, runtime

I'm trying to integrate Fellowship in this [PR](https://github.com/bifrost-finance/bifrost/pull/972/files#diff-d95a0d9c89d0dbeca1ef180360379f0258ced158f3c72626ae5723a5f37d7ea3R1801) according to https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/5205,
but when I run `make check-all` it gives the following error:

```rs
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(frame_system::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_timestamp::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_indices::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::Pallet<Runtime>, parachain_info::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_balances::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_transaction_payment::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_authorship::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_session::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_aura::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_aura_ext::Pallet<Runtime>, parachain_staking::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_democracy::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_collective::Pallet<Runtime, Instance1>, pallet_collective::Pallet<Runtime, Instance2>, pallet_elections_phragmen::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_membership::Pallet<Runtime, Instance1>, pallet_membership::Pallet<Runtime, Instance2>, pallet_conviction_voting::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_referenda::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_referenda::Pallet<Runtime, Instance2>, pallet_ranked_collective::Pallet<Runtime, Instance1>, governance::origins::custom_origins::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_whitelist::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_xcmp_queue::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_xcm::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_xcm::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_dmp_queue::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_utility::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_scheduler::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_proxy::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_multisig::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_identity::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_vesting::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_treasury::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_bounties::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_tips::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_preimage::Pallet<Runtime>, orml_xtokens::Pallet<Runtime>, orml_tokens::Pallet<Runtime>, orml_currencies::Pallet<Runtime>, orml_unknown_tokens::Pallet<Runtime>, orml_xcm::Pallet<Runtime>, zenlink_protocol::Pallet<Runtime>, merkle_distributor::Pallet<Runtime>, zenlink_stable_amm::Pallet<Runtime>, zenlink_swap_router::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_flexible_fee::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_salp::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_liquidity_mining::Pallet<Runtime, Instance2>, bifrost_liquidity_mining::Pallet<Runtime, Instance1>, bifrost_token_issuer::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_lightening_redeem::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_salp_lite::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_call_switchgear::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_vsbond_auction::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_asset_registry::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_vtoken_minting::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_slp::Pallet<Runtime>, xcm_interface::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_vstoken_conversion::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_farming::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_system_staking::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_system_maker::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_fee_share::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_cross_in_out::Pallet<Runtime>): PalletsInfoAccess` is not satisfied    --> runtime/bifrost-kusama/src/xcm_config.rs:596:29
    | 596 |     type PalletInstancesInfo = AllPalletsWithSystem;
    |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `PalletsInfoAccess` is not implemented for `(frame_system::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_timestamp::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_indices::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::Pallet<Runtime>, parachain_info::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_balances::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_transaction_payment::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_authorship::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_session::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_aura::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_aura_ext::Pallet<Runtime>, parachain_staking::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_democracy::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_collective::Pallet<Runtime, Instance1>, pallet_collective::Pallet<Runtime, Instance2>, pallet_elections_phragmen::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_membership::Pallet<Runtime, Instance1>, pallet_membership::Pallet<Runtime, Instance2>, pallet_conviction_voting::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_referenda::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_referenda::Pallet<Runtime, Instance2>, pallet_ranked_collective::Pallet<Runtime, Instance1>, governance::origins::custom_origins::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_whitelist::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_xcmp_queue::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_xcm::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_xcm::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_dmp_queue::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_utility::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_scheduler::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_proxy::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_multisig::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_identity::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_vesting::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_treasury::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_bounties::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_tips::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_preimage::Pallet<Runtime>, orml_xtokens::Pallet<Runtime>, orml_tokens::Pallet<Runtime>, orml_currencies::Pallet<Runtime>, orml_unknown_tokens::Pallet<Runtime>, orml_xcm::Pallet<Runtime>, zenlink_protocol::Pallet<Runtime>, merkle_distributor::Pallet<Runtime>, zenlink_stable_amm::Pallet<Runtime>, zenlink_swap_router::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_flexible_fee::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_salp::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_liquidity_mining::Pallet<Runtime, Instance2>, bifrost_liquidity_mining::Pallet<Runtime, Instance1>, bifrost_token_issuer::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_lightening_redeem::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_salp_lite::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_call_switchgear::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_vsbond_auction::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_asset_registry::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_vtoken_minting::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_slp::Pallet<Runtime>, xcm_interface::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_vstoken_conversion::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_farming::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_system_staking::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_system_maker::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_fee_share::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_cross_in_out::Pallet<Runtime>)`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `PalletsInfoAccess`:
              ()
              (TupleElement0, TupleElement1)
              (TupleElement0, TupleElement1, TupleElement2)
              (TupleElement0, TupleElement1, TupleElement2, TupleElement3)
              (TupleElement0, TupleElement1, TupleElement2, TupleElement3, TupleElement4)
              (TupleElement0, TupleElement1, TupleElement2, TupleElement3, TupleElement4, TupleElement5)
              (TupleElement0, TupleElement1, TupleElement2, TupleElement3, TupleElement4, TupleElement5, TupleElement6)
              (TupleElement0, TupleElement1, TupleElement2, TupleElement3, TupleElement4, TupleElement5, TupleElement6, TupleElement7)
            and 57 others note: required by a bound in `xcm_executor::Config::PalletInstancesInfo`    --> /home/yml/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-4038f27d5e4ea2e8/097ffd2/xcm/xcm-executor/src/config.rs:80:28
    | 80  |     type PalletInstancesInfo: PalletsInfoAccess;
    |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `xcm_executor::Config::PalletInstancesInfo`

    Checking polkadot-client v0.9.38 (https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot?branch=release-v0.9.38#097ffd24) error[E0277]: the trait bound `(frame_system::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_timestamp::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_indices::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::Pallet<Runtime>, parachain_info::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_balances::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_transaction_payment::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_authorship::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_session::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_aura::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_aura_ext::Pallet<Runtime>, parachain_staking::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_democracy::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_collective::Pallet<Runtime, Instance1>, pallet_collective::Pallet<Runtime, Instance2>, pallet_elections_phragmen::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_membership::Pallet<Runtime, Instance1>, pallet_membership::Pallet<Runtime, Instance2>, pallet_conviction_voting::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_referenda::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_referenda::Pallet<Runtime, Instance2>, pallet_ranked_collective::Pallet<Runtime, Instance1>, governance::origins::custom_origins::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_whitelist::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_xcmp_queue::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_xcm::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_xcm::Pallet<Runtime>, cumulus_pallet_dmp_queue::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_utility::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_scheduler::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_proxy::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_multisig::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_identity::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_vesting::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_treasury::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_bounties::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_tips::Pallet<Runtime>, pallet_preimage::Pallet<Runtime>, orml_xtokens::Pallet<Runtime>, orml_tokens::Pallet<Runtime>, orml_currencies::Pallet<Runtime>, orml_unknown_tokens::Pallet<Runtime>, orml_xcm::Pallet<Runtime>, zenlink_protocol::Pallet<Runtime>, merkle_distributor::Pallet<Runtime>, zenlink_stable_amm::Pallet<Runtime>, zenlink_swap_router::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_flexible_fee::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_salp::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_liquidity_mining::Pallet<Runtime, Instance2>, bifrost_liquidity_mining::Pallet<Runtime, Instance1>, bifrost_token_issuer::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_lightening_redeem::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_salp_lite::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_call_switchgear::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_vsbond_auction::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_asset_registry::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_vtoken_minting::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_slp::Pallet<Runtime>, xcm_interface::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_vstoken_conversion::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_farming::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_system_staking::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_system_maker::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_fee_share::Pallet<Runtime>, bifrost_cross_in_out::Pallet<Runtime>): OnGenesis` is not satisfied
```

Comment: Looks like according to your error message, the issue could be here: `runtime/bifrost-kusama/src/xcm_config.rs:596:29`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been fixed. The reason for the error is that the number of pallets in the runtime exceeds the limit. See [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/9762613a130235317467f66d6e6f46bfa30a5674/frame/support/src/lib.rs#L26).[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like according to your error message, the issue could be here: `runtime/bifrost-kusama/src/xcm_config.rs:596:29`

Looks like you do not have `AllPalletsWithSystem` imported.

Try:

```rust
use super::AllPalletsWithSystem
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Actually everything was working fine until I added FellowshipReferenda and FellowshipCollective(xcm_config.rs unchanged). From the prompt, it seems that the corresponding PalletsInfo cannot be obtained, but I don't know how to modify it.

Comment: Was this issue solved? Can you update with what worked for you?

Comment: See [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/9185/2424).